# Inequality related to spectral radius

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $E$ to $E$.

For $A = (A_1,\cdots,A_d)\in\mathcal{L}(E)^d$, the algebraic spectral radius of $A$ was given by
$$
r_a(A)=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}\left\|\sum_{f\in F(n,d)} A_f^* A_f\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}} =\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left\|\sum_{f\in F(n,d)} A_f^* A_f\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}} ,
$$
where $F(n,d):=\{f:\,\{1,\cdots,n\}\longrightarrow \{1,\cdots,d\}\}$ and $A_f:=A_{f(1)}\cdots A_{f(n)}$, for $f\in F(n,d)$.

> I don't understand why if $n=1$, we have
>   $$r_a(A)\leq  \|A\|:=\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^d\|A_kx\|^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}?$$

Comment: $n=1$ or $d=1$?

Comment: @s.harp $n=1$. I see this property in a paper.

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2159479?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @s.harp Do you understand me?

Comment: It might help to note that when $n=1$, 
$$\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^d\|A_kx\|^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^d|A_k|^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: @Surb i don't  understand when i use the  equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
$$r_a(A)\leq \left(\left\|\sum_{f\in \mathbf{F}(n,d)} \mathbf{A}_f^*\mathbf{A}_{f}\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}} \right),$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

If $n=1$, then 
$$r_a(A)\leq \left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^dA_k^* A_k \right\|^{1/2}=||A||.$$

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, you switched the indices from the paper. The "$n=1$" from the paper is your "$d=1$".

So what the paper is saying is that, when $d=1$, 
$$
r_a(A)=\lim_n\|A_1^{n*}A_1^n\|^{1/2n}=\lim_n\|A_1^n\|^{1/n}=r(A_1).
$$
Also
$$
\|A_1^n\|^{1/n}\leq\|A_1\|, 
$$
so
$$
r_a(A)\leq r(A_1)\leq \|A_1\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A_1x\|.
$$